# How to determine if a scrollbar for a CListCtrl is displaying?

Tags: mfc, clistctrl

I have a class that is derived from a CListCtrl.  I want the widths of all the columns to total the width of the display Window, so that I don't get the bottom scrollbar.  I can get the width of standard scrollbars vai the `GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVSCROLL)` call, but I don't know how to tell if the vertical scrollbar is active.  I've tried to use:

```
auto pScrollbar = GetScrollBarCtrl(SB_VERT);
auto is_visible = pScrollbar && pScrollbar->IsWindowVisible();
```

But `pScrollbar` is always a `nullptr`.  I've looked around and some ppl are saying that the scrollbars are not always windows and may be draw in by hand (ugh!) and may not be a Window at all. This will make my life more difficult.  Ideas?

Comment: I don't know about the details of list controls, but [There are two types of scrollbars](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040510-00/?p=39413).

Comment: You have to use the client rect and divide it according to the desired widths of your columns and set the last column remaining width

Answer (score 1):

From my linked question ([How to stop the bottom scrollbar from a CListCtrl from displaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48896439/how-to-stop-the-bottom-scrollbar-from-a-clistctrl-from-displaying/48917494#48917494)), I was using:

```
void CMyListCtrl::ResizeLastColumn()
{
    LVCOLUMN column;
    column.mask = LVCF_WIDTH;
    LONG maxWidth = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < lastColumnIndex; ++i)
    {
        GetColumn(i, &column);
        maxWidth += column.cx;
    }
    CRect wndRect;
    GetWindowRect(&wndRect);

    SetColumnWidth(lastColumnIndex, wndRect.Width() - maxWidth - 4);
}
```

to resize the columns to the width of the client area.  Turns out, by using `GetClientRect()` instead, I don't have to subtract `-4` or the vertical scrollbar width, making this no longer an issue.