# How to stop the bottom scrollbar from a CListCtrl from displaying?

Tags: mfc

I have a `CListCtrl` which is dynamically resized with the dialogue.  I used a `WM_SIZE` message handler in the derived `CListCtrl` to resize the columns such that the total is the width of the control - 4, where the - 4 is to indicate the width of the border.

When I make the dialogue bigger, the control resizes correctly and I don't get the bottom scrollbar.  However when I shrink the control, I sometimes get the horizontal scrollbar showing up.

```
void CMyListCtrl::OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy)
{
    CListCtrl::OnSize(nType, cx, cy);
    ResizeLastColumn();
}

void CMyListCtrl::ResizeLastColumn()
{
    LVCOLUMN column;
    column.mask = LVCF_WIDTH;
    LONG maxWidth = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < lastColumnIndex; ++i)
    {
        GetColumn(i, &column);
        maxWidth += column.cx;
    }
    CRect wndRect;
    GetWindowRect(&wndRect);

    SetColumnWidth(lastColumnIndex, wndRect.Width() - maxWidth - 4);
}
```

It is like the `WM_SIZE` message is getting to the control before the control is finally resized.

This is related to [How to determine if a scrollbar for a CListCtrl is displaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48896284/how-to-determine-if-a-scrollbar-for-a-clistctrl-is-displaying).  However, this question is not dealing with the right scrollbar, and is assuming that it is not being displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resizing the window generates a message to test for horizontal scroll. `SetColumnWidth` will also generate the same message. It depends how ListView handles this internally, but a vertical scroll could also come in and go, this will change the client area, so the code may have to make recursive calls to figure out if the scroll should be visible or not. You can see this can easily run in to problems.

Try resizing the columns in `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED`, before calling the default procedure. Use `SetRedraw` to stop redundant paint messages.

```
ON_WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED()
...
void CMyListCtrl::OnWindowPosChanged(WINDOWPOS *wpos)
{
    SetRedraw(FALSE);
    ResizeLastColumn();
    SetRedraw(TRUE);
    CListCtrl::OnWindowPosChanged(wpos);
}
```

You can use `GetClientRect` for the client area, then you don't need to subtract the border thickness (which is not always 4).

```
void ResizeLastColumn()
{
    int maxwidth = 0;
    int index = GetHeaderCtrl()->GetItemCount() - 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < index; ++i)
        maxwidth += GetColumnWidth(i);
    CRect rc;
    GetClientRect(&rc);
    SetColumnWidth(index, rc.Width() - maxwidth);
}
```

Also `GetHeaderCtrl()->GetItemCount()` returns the number of columns.

Comment: Oh. That sounds promising.

Comment: Worked beautifully.  Also made my other linked question moot.

Comment: I had tried `OnWindowPosChanged` and it was working, it seems works with your system too. But now it doesn't work sometimes! I added a second method with `SetRedraw` which works consistently on Windows 10. I'll try it later on Win7.

Comment: Ah, I had just put the `CListCtrl::OnWindowPosChanged(wpos)` at the end rather than the beginning and it was fine, like in your updated code.

Comment: One odd behaviour I found which I don't know if it is related or not is that if I insert enough rows such that it overflows the client area, and I make the control taller, it hides all the rows until I make it small enough to show the vertical scrollbar and move it.  After that, it works fine.  Maybe related to not turning off and on the redraw?

Comment: Nope, not related.  Adding the `SetRedraw()` calls didn't do anything.

Comment: I tested the above code it in Win10 and Win7, it seems to work right consistently. I couldn't duplicate the error you describe when there are too many rows. Note that when vertical scroll bar appears, the client area gets smaller, so column size decreases.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the exact same issue, with the exact same Use Case.

To disable the horizontal scroll bar altogether, you add a message handler for WM_NCCALCSIZE

Using the Class Wizard this adds the following to your message map:

```
ON_WM_NCCALCSIZE()
```

In the implementation of this handler, you modify the style to disable the horizontal scroll bar.

```
void CMyListCtrl::OnNcCalcSize(BOOL bCalcValidRects, NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS* lpncsp)
{
    ModifyStyle(WS_HSCROLL, 0); // disable the horizontal scroll bar

    __super::OnNcCalcSize(bCalcValidRects, lpncsp);
}
```

In my own implementation of ResizeLastColumn(), which is similar to yours, I subtract ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVSCROLL) from the width to account for the vertical scroll bar.

I realise this reply is rather late, but hopefully it will help someone.

(Edited to remove mentions of some problems I am having because a) they are off-topic and b) because I think they stem from me not using the Doc-View architecture and things not being wired up correctly as a result. I'm going to re-think my approach.)